# Certbot cannot obtain certificate when firewall is on

Tags: debian, ssl, shell, ufw, certbot

I have a script that creates a new nginx configuration for some domain and within this script, I am requesting new certificate via `certbot`. I am running newest debian server with `ufw` enabled (configuration set up mentioned below). And I am running this shell script as a root.

It is a simple call to request ssl certificate for some domain and pass it to nginx configuration

```
certbot --nginx -d "$DOMAIN_NAME" -d "www.$DOMAIN_NAME"
```

When this line of code runs in the script, I get this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

The interesting thing is that **when i disable the ufw, certificate is obtained without any issues.** The things getting even more interesting when I show you the ufw configuration. I am running nginx server so I have to have 80/443 ports open to server HTTP(S) requests and according to certbot documentation, certbot uses these ports for its own function as well.

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
465/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
465/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? The fact that disabling ufw solves the issue tells me there must be problem in that firewall, but according to everything I was able to find this is a configuration that should work.